# What does Stack Exchange use for the edit feature?

Tags: support

The whole feature is pretty dandy. Letting a user edit your post and you can see the before and after with highlights on the changes. What does Stack Exchange use for this feature? I'm hoping its some sort of open source plugin.

Comment: If you need something like that, you could ask on [softwarerecs.se] SE for a solution (which would not necessarily be what SE uses): specify exactly what you need (e.g., the features it should have) and what you need it for (your use case)